# change array structure in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to change my array structure this is my array

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0.2
        [1] => 0.10
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0.4
        [1] => 0.21
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0.6
        [1] => 0.45
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0.8
        [1] => 0.75
    )

)
```

I want to change this array in this form:-

```
([[0.2,0.10], [0.4,0.21],[0.6,0.45],[0.8, 0.75]])
```

Comment: Your result is identical to the original.

Comment: They're just two different ways of displaying the same kind of numerically-indexed array.

Comment: @Barmar you are right, but when i try this dataTable.addRows([[0.2,0.10], [0.4,0.21],[0.6,0.45],[0.8, 0.75]]) its run correct but when I use  dataTable.addRows([data1]); its show error message and error is that Uncaught Error: Every row given must be either null or an array.  and data1 value is  that Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0.2
        [1] => 0.10
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0.4
        [1] => 0.21
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0.6
        [1] => 0.45
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0.8
        [1] => 0.75
    )

) when I console data1

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use the output of `var_dump()` from PHP as an array.

Comment: If you want to send an array from PHP to Javascript, use `json_encode()`. `var_dump()` is meant for displaying to humans.

Comment: @Barmar  please tell me how to remove key from this array , actually I am using only javascriptcode not php code Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0.2
        [1] => 0.10
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0.4
        [1] => 0.21
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0.6
        [1] => 0.45
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0.8
        [1] => 0.75
    )

)

Comment: That will never happen in Javascript, that's not its syntax of arrays. It must be coming from PHP.

Comment: After using json _encode() it gives an array like this:[["0.2","0.10"],["0.4","0.21"],["0.6","0.45"],["0.8","0.75"]]  but i want array like [[0.2,0.10], [0.4,0.21],[0.6,0.45],[0.8, 0.75]]

Comment: Javascript will automatically convert strings to numbers when necessary. But you can call `parseFloat()` on the values in the array if you want.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, yes when I use json_encode() its give same value which I want like [[0.2,0.1],[0.4,0.21],[0.6,0.45],[0.8,0.75]] when I print data1 but when I pass this value in dataTable.addRows(data1) its gave same error message  Uncaught Error: Argument given to addRows must be either a number or an array  but when I used hadcode value like that dataTable.addRows([[0.2,0.1],[0.4,0.21],[0.6,0.45],[0.8,0.75]] ) it working corectlly please tell me where I am wrong

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof data1)` say?

Comment: You need to use `JSON.parse()` in the Javascript code to convert the JSON back into an array.

Comment: @Barmar  yes  it's working correctly .